# Issue creating JWT token

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I have a Java Spring application in which I am trying to create a JWT token, but I am getting the following error:

`java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=111, too big.`

Code below:

```
public static String createJwt(String publicKey, String privateKey, String issuer, String userId) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            RSAPrivateKey rsaPrivateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) getPrivateKey(privateKey);
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) getPublicKey(publicKey);
            Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(rsaPublicKey, rsaPrivateKey);
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return JWT.create()
                    .withIssuer(issuer)
                    .withJWTId(userId)
                    .withIssuedAt(new Date(now))
                    .withExpiresAt(new Date(now + 15 * 60 * 1000))
                    .sign(algorithm);
        } catch (JWTCreationException e) {
            log.error("Jwt secure token creation failed. Exception: ", e);
            throw new AuthenticationException("JWT creation failed");
        }
    }

private static PublicKey getPublicKey(String base64Key) {
        byte[] rawKey = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Key);
        X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(rawKey);
        KeyFactory kf;
        try {
            kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return kf.generatePublic(ks);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Client Configuration issue. Public key error", Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        }
    }

private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String base64Key) {
        byte[] rawKey = Base64.decodeBase64(base64Key);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rawKey);
        KeyFactory kf;
        try {
            kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            return kf.generatePrivate(ks);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException("Client Configuration issue. Private key error", Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        }
    }
```

The error is getting thrown at line: `kf.generatePublic(ks)` and `kf.generatePrivate(ks)`.

I am using 512 bit RSA keys (https://csfieldguide.org.nz/en/interactives/rsa-key-generator/)

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAlU2XVqKMxVkkBGM/
C/fTpAIe2oCSDGxRcAyEUsyO8N0LVJOGv3cGK6C4eoaPxvmPaMDBagYe2CcEGnaY
06l4kwIDAQABAkAHnj3qncCxEStVTfsZkTurUrBgVc8d8yj0nq7hyq5Ae/I77SKj
ZwDfberj+KDX185w9ehNmf93fkiBXtIiJd0BAiEA/5saOhZUxh7OveLugHdwHNOY
R1B/3T6vc4kXMWeYf4kCIQCViIbiDg+MuZ73/3B+vR0tUXTva2pO9YFdJj9J82p0
OwIgJcHyqNv9n9qTLaelFaMPE6MKHpa8nKES5907aNflxgkCIHI8/28r9s038i7c
w4DP0b6RgJh4o5r3DIGxeqBwil+JAiBDeBJgON+HvDP8ab5SAyPDBA+/WTTLdSag
X6vUH20ANw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJVNl1aijMVZJARjPwv306QCHtqAkgxs
UXAMhFLMjvDdC1SThr93BiuguHqGj8b5j2jAwWoGHtgnBBp2mNOpeJMCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

which are passed to `createJwt` function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. Remove the headers and footers from the private and public keys, i.e:

PRIVATE KEY:

```
MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAlU2XVqKMxVkkBGM/
C/fTpAIe2oCSDGxRcAyEUsyO8N0LVJOGv3cGK6C4eoaPxvmPaMDBagYe2CcEGnaY
06l4kwIDAQABAkAHnj3qncCxEStVTfsZkTurUrBgVc8d8yj0nq7hyq5Ae/I77SKj
ZwDfberj+KDX185w9ehNmf93fkiBXtIiJd0BAiEA/5saOhZUxh7OveLugHdwHNOY
R1B/3T6vc4kXMWeYf4kCIQCViIbiDg+MuZ73/3B+vR0tUXTva2pO9YFdJj9J82p0
OwIgJcHyqNv9n9qTLaelFaMPE6MKHpa8nKES5907aNflxgkCIHI8/28r9s038i7c
w4DP0b6RgJh4o5r3DIGxeqBwil+JAiBDeBJgON+HvDP8ab5SAyPDBA+/WTTLdSag
X6vUH20ANw==
```

and PUBLIC KEY:

```
MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAJVNl1aijMVZJARjPwv306QCHtqAkgxs
UXAMhFLMjvDdC1SThr93BiuguHqGj8b5j2jAwWoGHtgnBBp2mNOpeJMCAwEAAQ==
```

Hope this helps others who face this issue!!